# Incomprehensible input behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

There was a problem entering the fields of class. At the time of calling the add_well function, the default class fields specified in init function are displayed in the console. I don't understand why this behavior occurs and how to get rid of it. Can you help me?

[image: Console out]

```
def InputConsole(self, param):
   return input(param)

#class of well
class well:
    def __init__(self):
        self.code_name = ''
        self.depth = 0
        self.pressure = 0
        self.work = False
    
def input_properties(self):
        print("-------- ADD WELL --------")
        print('Code name:  ')
        self.code_name = InputConsole(self, self.code_name)
        print('Depth:  ')
        self.depth = InputConsole(self, self.depth)
        print('Pressure:  ')
        self.pressure = InputConsole(self, self.pressure)
        print('Work:  ')
        self.work = InputConsole(self, self.work)


#class of field, container class
class field():
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = dict() 
        self.id_max = 0
    
def add_well(self):
    wl = well()
    wl.input_properties()
    self.field[self.id_max] = wl
    self.id_max += 1
    print('Well was added\n\n')

def print_console(self):
    print(self.field)
    if self.id_max != 0 :
        print("-------- INFO ABOUT FIELD --------")
        for i in range(self.id_max):
            self.field[i].print_properties()
            print('')
    else:
        print('List is empty\n\n')

def main():
    field = field()
    field.add_well()

main()
```

Comment: Your code is poorly indented. Please fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `input()` with a parameter uses the parameter as a prompt. Change the calls of `InputConsole(self, self.code_name)` to `InputConsole(self, “Enter code name: “)` and so on.

In addition, there’s really no reason you should be making an InputConsole function. You should also not be using `self` as a parameter for some of these methods, because your InputConsole, add_well, and print_console functions are not members of a class.